# Middle vertically align inline-block div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `inline-block` divs next to each other. The left one is of variable height and the right one just has a button inside.

I want the right div to always be vertically centered with the left div.

Here's how it looks: https://jsfiddle.net/6xm23fv6/1/

Does anybody know if it's possible to keep them `inline-block` and still vertically center one div relative to the other?

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.inlineDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}

#inlineDiv1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#inlineDiv2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inlineDiv1" class="inlineDiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <div id="inlineDiv2" class="inlineDiv">
    <button>Hi</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align` should work:

```
#inlineDiv1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6xm23fv6/2/

EDIT:
For inline-blocks after this, I think the only we to 'reset' the vertical alignment is to wrap the first two in a block that's also set to `display: inline-block` with a new `vertical-align: top`

for example: https://jsfiddle.net/6xm23fv6/4/

Comment: Ok, sorry for not specifying this in the question, but if I have another `inline-block` div on the right hand side, is there a way to cancel the `vertical-align: middle;` for it so that it's top aligned with the left hand div? i.e. just the middle div is vertically centered

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that is by wrapping the first two in the their own in-line unit. See other fiddle above.

Comment: Actually I found out how to, I just put `vertical-align: top` on the last one.

Answer (score 1):

try:
{vertical-align: middle;}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add a container around both elements and make it `display:flex;`. Check the code snippet.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.inlineDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}

#inlineDiv1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#inlineDiv2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.ctn {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="ctn">
  <div id="inlineDiv1" class="inlineDiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi there</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </div>
  
  <div id="inlineDiv2" class="inlineDiv">
    <button>Hi</button>
  </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```